# Rails carrierwave link generated different from s3 storage link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, rails-api

I created a rails api but I have a problem with image upload.
I'm using carrierwave , the upload of picture is working but I get a wrong link.

Example :

This is the link I find in the RESTful api :

https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql/uploads/driver/picture/35/imagename.png

But when I check S3 storage I find a different link :

https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql/gpsql/gpsql/uploads/driver/picture/35/imagename.png

This is initializer for s3 carrierwave :

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws' # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: 'AWS', # required
      aws_access_key_id: '...', # required
      aws_secret_access_key: '...', # required
      region: 'us-west-2',
      path_style: true,
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'gpsql' # required
  config.asset_host = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql'
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

In picture uploader :

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

How can I fix the link that is shown in the RESTful api also why there is so much "bucket name" in amazon link why not something straightforward link/bucketname/image.png

For the first link I find in restful api it doesn't work at all I get access denied or key not found for the second one in amazon s3 it works without any problem.

Comment: have u tried without `config.asset_host`, remove it and restart rails server.

Comment: yes I tried. it wasn't there in first place it's one of the solution I tried but nothing worked sadly. @7urkm3n

Comment: have you tried to delete the `config.asset_host` and add the host and endpoint within your fog credentials?:  `host: 's3.example.com', endpoint: 'https://regionendpointhere.amazonaws.com `? as stated in documentation of fog + s3?

Comment: @jenvvv I tried but didn't work. I don't know why but adding : `config.fog_public=true` fixed the link now present is correct 100%.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem is this

`config.asset_host = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql'`

it should be

`config.asset_host = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com'`

Anyway I don't know why it's repeating twice...

So, if you can you should fix it in the configuration and move the folder in S3 to the proper place

If you can't move it I would try to change the store dir to `"gpsql/gpsql/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"`

I'm not sure if that works but that would be my first step

Comment: Sadly the solution didn't work at all. The link is still different than S3 storage ...

for S3 storage : https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql/gpsql/gpsql/gpsql/uploads/driver/picture/88/image.png

and for restful api I have https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpsql/gpsql/uploads/driver/picture/88/image.png